# MySQL Table Crashed Needs Repair, but Doesn't seem to Repair?

Tags: mysql

I am getting the error:

```
Table 'feed_data' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

So I run `REPAIR TABLE feed_data` (repeatedly) and get the following result:

```
+----------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table          | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                      |
+----------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| mydb.feed_data | repair | Error    | Table 'feed_data' is marked as crashed and should be repaired | 
| mydb.feed_data | repair | status   | Table is already up to date                                   | 
+----------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

The table still shows as crashed.
Why won't the table repair when I run the repair table command? What else can I do to repair the crashed table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shutdown the DB and use [myisamchk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html).

Comment: I once had to export that data, the rebuild the table and reimport the data because myisamchk didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to have mysql perform automatic repairs each time you restart mysql

Just add this to the `[mysqld]` section of /etc/my.cnf

```
myisam-recover=<\option[,option]*>
```

Here is a more detailed explanation of the options as explained in the book

[image]

[MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127) Chapter 30 Section 30.5 Pages 444,445

Here are the options for [**myisam-recover**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_myisam-recover-options)

- DEFAULT for the default checking
- BACKUP tells the server to make a backup of any table that it must change
- FORCE causes table recovery to be performed even if it would cause the loss of more than one row of data
- QUICK performs quick recovery: Tables that have no holes resulting from deletes or updates are skipped